# Does Windows support "/" for Navigation?

Tags: php, wordpress, windows

I'm currently using linux and in my PHP scripts, I've used slash many times.
it takes time to install and config xampp in win so i thought this is fastest 
like this

```
foreach (scanAllDir($filePath) as $childFilename) {
     $result[] = $filename . '/' . $childFilename;
}
```

and

```
$customCssFile = fopen(__DIR__ . '/templates/custom-css.css', "w");
```

is this scripts works in windows?
thanks

Comment: You should be using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: Yes, it should work.  Q: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I believe any recent (maintained) versions of Windows tolerate forward slashes for file paths.

Comment: Although `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is provided for determining which slash to use, I rarely find this constant useful outside of UI display context's.  Both slashes will work the same on Windows however the backslash **will not** work on Unix/Linux.